# Only manually connect to bluetooth device on macOS

Tags: bluetooth

I would like for my macOS machine to only connect to a paired device when manually told to do so. It should not automatically connect as to not steal the connection from other devices. My current solution is to constantly unpair and repair the device which is quite cumbersome. This is a feature in every other OS, so I expect this to also be available on macOS.